# Cabal Cabal-Install not working, strange error

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I need to install Yesod and dependancies trough Cabal, unfortunately I'm not able to update cabal. Shell output:

```
...$ sudo cabal install cabal-install 
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.18.0.2...

/tmp/24453.c:1:12:
     warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
1 warning generated.
Building cabal-install-1.18.0.2...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.18.0.2...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HTTP-4000.2.8-cdf033f9d7051824f52cd5101df67509
    (use -v for more information)
Failed to install cabal-install-1.18.0.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.18.0.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Nothing really makes sense to me.

Comment: if you try a `sudo cabal install -v cabal-install` ?

Comment: I have tried this, here's the paste: http://lpaste.net/94950

Comment: Which platform are you on? you can try refreshing ghc cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139263/cabal-install-failing-osx-many-unsatisfied-packages

Comment: Running Mac OSX Maverick. Recaching ghc gave a different output but still failure: http://lpaste.net/94951

Comment: Here is something strongly related https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1378 . Doesn't seem to be fixed tough.

Comment: Yeah It's probably the same. It seems to be missing some C header files...

Comment: It's more that it cannot find them. The missing headers are too common to not be found. Did you try with --extra-include-dirs and --extra-lib-dirs ?

Comment: Yes, also tried changing files according to this: https://github.com/IreneKnapp/cabal/commit/3be278234f9442dd2e65a838ee64a79a3e95437b

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40162/discussion-between-remi-benoit-and-swenmulderij)

Comment: Mavericks dropped support for `gcc` and that's causing some problems for GHC. To find out more take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579577/installing-building-ghc-with-osx-mavericks-ghc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found here: [Installing & Building GHC with OSX Mavericks GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579577/installing-building-ghc-with-osx-mavericks-ghc)

The commandline tools from apple are required!

Thanks!

Comment: This did not fix it for me

Comment: Same here. I have the command line tools, and I still get the failure.